# How to implement javascript file into jquery? for ipad / implement iscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I am currently trying to implement this into my current code:
http://cubiq.org/iscroll

I have been using jquery this whole time in my code, but iscroll was created in all javascript.
Is there any way to get this to work without having to change all of the javascript into jquery format?
I am developing for an ipad and I need the ability to scroll through a div. Scrollbars do not work...

If it's not possible...
Does anyone know of any good plugins that may let me scroll vertically in a div using jquery?

This will ONLY be used for the ipad, so it wouldn't matter if it doesn't work in certain browsers as long as it works on the ipad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something amazing to use for anyone who is interested:

[jScrollTouch](http://www.dealinium.com/common/jScrollTouch)

I tried so many different ones but this seems to be the easiest and almost the only one that would work for the ipad. This also returns to a normal scroll bar if your on a regular desktop/laptop so you can still use it when not using ipad :)

Answer (score 0):

The [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin works very well. I couldn't even get iscroll demo to work in chrome.

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't work, I would suspect that it should work similar to webkit as that's what in Safari, but alas.

Answer (score 0):

Normal javascript should work fine side-by-side with jquery code. Just include the file and code it seperately.

Comment: It seems to always give me errors from that one js file. addEventListener and whatnot doesn't seem to let it work because it isn't jquery.